# Eclpise CDT: View all macros defined in source code in a given directory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT, How can I see all the macros defined in all the source files under a given directory tree?  I don't want to see any macros that are defined in include files that exist outside the given directory tree.

In 'Open Element' dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), I can uncheck all element types, check only the "Macro" type and then search for '*'.  This would show all the macros from the index.  There is no control to further filter it based on a "selected resource".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this one.

1. Click on the directory in the Project Explorer on which you want to perform the search recursively.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to get the Search dialog.  Go to the 'C/C++ Search' tab.
3. In 'Search For' box, uncheck 'Any Element' and check 'Macro'.
4. In 'Limit To' box, uncheck 'All Occurrences' and check '"Definitions'.
5. In 'Scope' box, select 'Selected resources'.
6. Set the search string to '*' (without quotes).
7. Finally, hit the 'Search' button.

[image]