# View all macros defined in source code at a given position in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, c, macros, eclipse-cdt

Is there a possibility to view the live macros defined at the current position in the code, in Eclipse CDT?

I think that there could be a way to do this, since eclipse is smart enough to follow my header files included within the window `Window > Show view > Include Browser`. It can also, as of today, figure out what macros are defined and gray out areas of i.e. `#ifdef` which are currently not going to be compiled.

The only thing that I feel it could be missing is if I use defines in en external makefile, however they can be simulated and added to the live index via the project settings.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409010/eclpise-cdt-view-all-macros-defined-in-source-code-in-a-given-directory) is, e.g. not what I am looking for, since it would list all macros in the file/project/workspace. I want to know depending on, lets say, where I currently have my cursor in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Type in the editor window:

```
#ifdef
```

And then press `Ctrl-Space`. You will see the long list of all active macros

*Update*

1) This method correctly **not shows** macro before it is defined and **shows** after

2) However it seems Eclipse CDT has an error in handling `#undef` and this method **incorrectly shows** macro after it is undefined. I have filed a bug report http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472198.

Comment: It does not seem to work the way I intended. It is showing every known macro, not regarding whether it is "currently" defined or not. If I write, e.g. `#undef` on the row above it, it is still shown in the list. Is it made any clearer?

Comment: It seems to be an error in Eclipse CDT. So I have filed a bug report http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472198

Comment: The bug has been answered. As stated by the assignee, I think that it is working as inteded. I simply don't think that there is (currently) a good way to do this.